# Php como se ponenla llaves

Tags: php

Alguien me puede solucionarcomo insertar las llaves de separacion de los items?

```
$url = "http://www.ffcv.es/ncompeticiones/server.php?action=getActa&tmp=2017/2018&jor=3&cmp=48&idl=0201073211&idv=0201128231&id=2127995";

    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $array = json_decode($data, true);  

    $result = [];

    foreach($array as $colors => $color){       
        if($colors == "amonestacionesLocal"){
            foreach($color as $key => $value){
                foreach($value as $clave => $valor){
                    $result[]=$valor;
                }                           
            }
        }    

        if($colors == "amonestacionesVisitante"){
            foreach($color as $key => $value){
                foreach($value as $clave => $valor){
                    $result[]=$valor;
                }                           
            }
        }    

    }       

    echo json_encode($result);
```

asi es como me sale:

```
[
{
"valor": "634cef1b26b8a95c7229788b610b02bbf8ba7c8b",
"idJugador": "Nombre del jugador"
},
{
"valor": "Montesinos Piedra, Jaime",
"idJugador": "Nombre del jugador"
},
{
"valor": "amarilla",
"idJugador": "Nombre del jugador"
},
{
"valor": "53'",
"idJugador": "Nombre del jugador"
},.......
```

Comment: No entiendo lo que necesitas, debes ser un poco más especifico, pero veo que estas intentando convertir un array a json, para eso puedes usar la funcion echo json_encode($array);
Modifica el arreglo que te retorna la funcion json_decode y luego la imprimes.

Comment: Veras, si abres la url veras que esta un array=amonestacionesLocal y otro array=amonestacionesVisitante, pues bien lo que quiero es juntarlos y ordenarlos por el orden del minuto. gracias

Comment: En ese caso puedes unirlos y enviarlos con json_encode.. Ya te escribo un ejemplo..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba creando un nuevo array y usando json_encode, algo asi:

```
$url = "http://www.ffcv.es/ncompeticiones/server.php?action=getActa&tmp=2017/2018&jor=3&cmp=48&idl=0201073211&idv=0201128231&id=2127995";

$data = file_get_contents($url);
$array = json_decode($data, true);

$result = [];

foreach($array as $colors => $color){

    if($colors == "amonestacionesLocal"){
        foreach($color as $key => $value){
            $result[]=array(
                "idJugadorLocal"=>$value['idJugador'],
                "nombreLocal"=>$value['nombre'],
                "tarjetaLocal"=>$value['tarjeta'],
                "minutoLocal"=>$value['minuto'],
                "minuto"=>$value['minuto'],
            );
        }
    }

    if($colors == "amonestacionesVisitante"){
        foreach($color as $key => $value){
            $result[]=array(
                "idJugadorVisi"=>$value['idJugador'],
                "nombreVisi"=>$value['nombre'],
                "tarjetaVisi"=>$value['tarjeta'],
                "minutoVisi"=>$value['minuto'],
                "minuto"=>$value['minuto'],
            );
        }
    }
}

usort($result, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['minuto'] - $b['minuto'];
});

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: pero faltan las claves ylas llaves para separarlos,idJugador"nombre:

Comment: Puedes armar el arreglo como lo necesites:

 $result[]=array('valor'=>$valor,'idJugador'=>"Nombre del jugador");

Comment: Gracias voy a ver si me sale.

Comment: pues no me sale

Comment: Indica el formato que necesitas obtener para ayudarte.

Comment: post 1 editado y mostrando como sale, pero deberian estar los 4 valores dentro de as mismas llaves y diferente nombre.

Comment: Actualicé mi respuesta. ahi tienes todos los valores.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87692/discussion-between-rafel-c-f-and-jhoubert-rincon).